Comparison of .NET Key value pair Collections
I write in C# and am faced with the requirement of storing/retrieving a large number of string Key Value pairs from disk. To minimize the total amount of Ram consumed by the application, I would read the Key-Value pair database by specific Keys, process them, and then move on to other keys.
I currently utilize C# Dictionaries & Concurrent Dictionaries to hold data in memory that needs to be inserted/retrieved fast, However this approach is not scalable for larger scale applications. I have also tried databases like SQLite/SQL Server where a simple table would hold Key and value columns(with Key Column set as Unique Primary Key) but accessing single value for a Key is generally slow, mainly due to the round-trip cost of running each query.
I have come across the option to use ZoneTree or RocksDB to hold key-value pairs along with some other options.
My Question is following:

How Can RocksDB or ZoneTree be used to hold string key value Pairs?
How does the performance of insert/Fetch compare with in-memory collections like a concurrent Dictionary.
Between RocksDB & ZoneTree which one would offer the most optimal memory utilization?


"I write in .NET" No you don't, you write in C#.

The numbers of NoumanQ tests are as below.
ZoneTree is %500 faster on inserts and %10 faster on reads. (This is for sequential reads. On random reads, ZoneTree is 100% faster in default configuration. Block cache configuration affects read performance of both databases.)
The huge difference between NoumanQ's benchmark results and mine is because of the following: https://github.com/koculu/ZoneTree/issues/58
.NET 8.0 introduced a major but hidden change to FileStream internals. This has affected the performance of ZoneTree and it is already fixed on latest version (v1.7.1).
https://github.com/koculu/ZoneTree/releases/tag/release-v1.7.1
The only change in the test code is:
The CompleteRunningTasks() call is moved before
Console.WriteLine($"Execution Finished"); to make both tests fair.

ZoneTree's Memory usage can be controlled by various parameters:

MutableSegmentMaxItemCount

MaximumReadOnlySegmentCount

ThresholdForMergeOperationStart


Additionally, you can throttle your inserts by Thread.Sleep(xxx) to reduce the memory consumption when the compaction does not catch the speed of the insertions.
There are also events to react to ZoneTree's internal activities.
As a side note, it does not make sense to compare Concurrent Dictionary with Sorted Key Value Stores.
Because Concurrent Dictionary does not sort the keys.
Fair comparison would be with SortedDictionary.
Disk utilization depends on the CompressionMethod and it can be changed via disk segment options and via wal options.
More details here.

After Some research I have been able to find an answer to my question. Here is how I setup a benchmark that demonstrates how RocksDB or ZoneTree would compare for storing Key-Value Pair data, a comparison of their memory utilization and insert/Fetch performance for ~10Million items.
Here is my code, this is written in .NET 8 Console Application. It was run on an Intel Core i7-11th Gen processor, 64GBs of RAM, SSD on a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 2 in 1:
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RocksDbSharp;
using Tenray.ZoneTree.Comparers;
using Tenray.ZoneTree.Serializers;
using Tenray.ZoneTree;
using static TestRocksDb.Program;

namespace TestRocksDb
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static int MaxItems = 10000000;

        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestZoneTreePerformanceSingleThread();
            Console.WriteLine("--------");

            TestConcurrentDictionaryPerformanceSingleThread();
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            TestRocksDBPerformanceSingleThread();
            Console.WriteLine("--------");

            TestConcurrentDictionaryPerformanceMultiTaskThread();
            Console.WriteLine("--------");

            TestRocksDBPerformanceMultiThread();
            Console.WriteLine("--------");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static void TestConcurrentDictionaryPerformanceSingleThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Trial for Single thread performance of Concurrent Dictionary");

            
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            {
                long totalInsertTime = 0;

                // Create a ConcurrentBag with 100,000 Student items
                var bag = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Student>();
                var random = new Random();
                stopwatch.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                {
                    var student = new Student
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Name = $"Student{i}",
                        Age = random.Next(18, 25),
                        GPA = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 4.0, 2),
                        Address = $"Address {i}",
                        PhoneNumber = $"555-0100{i:D4}",
                        Email = $"student{i}@example.com",
                        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-random.Next(1000)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                    };
    
                    bag.TryAdd(i.ToString(), student);
                }

                    

                stopwatch.Stop();
                totalInsertTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to insert " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
               
                // Measure the time taken to read items

                stopwatch.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                {

                    var value = bag[i.ToString()];
                   
                }

                stopwatch.Stop();
                double totalReadTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to read " + MaxItems + " items: " + totalReadTime + " ms");

                // Additional metrics
                double avgInsertTime =Math.Round( (totalInsertTime / (double)MaxItems)*1000,1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average insert time per item: {avgInsertTime} us");

                double avgReadTime =Math.Round( (totalReadTime / (double)MaxItems)*1000,1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average read time per item: {avgReadTime} us");

                Console.WriteLine($"Test Finished");
            }

        }

        public static void TestRocksDBPerformanceSingleThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Trial for Single thread performance of RocksDB");

            bool InsertAllowed = true;
            bool DeleteEarlierRecords = true;
            string dbPath = "rocksdb";

            if (Directory.Exists(dbPath) && DeleteEarlierRecords)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deleting Earlier database directory");

                Directory.Delete(dbPath, true);
            }

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Rocks Db Trial, Max Concurrent Tasks: 1, MaxItems: " + MaxItems);

            // Directory to store the RocksDB database

            stopwatch.Start();
            var options = new DbOptions().SetCreateIfMissing(true);

            // Initialize RocksDB
            using (var db = RocksDb.Open(options, dbPath))
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"DB Initialization Time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                long totalInsertTime = 0;

                if (InsertAllowed)
                {
                    var random = new Random();
                    stopwatch.Restart();

                    for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                    {
                        var student = new Student
                        {
                            Id = i,
                            Name = $"Student{i}",
                            Age = random.Next(18, 25),
                            GPA = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 4.0, 2),
                            Address = $"Address {i}",
                            PhoneNumber = $"555-0100{i:D4}",
                            Email = $"student{i}@example.com",
                            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-random.Next(1000)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                        };

                        string serializedStudent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(student);

                        db.Put(i.ToString(), serializedStudent);

                    }

                    

                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    totalInsertTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to insert " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Insertion would be skipped.");
                // Measure the time taken to read items

                List<double> times = new List<double>();
                stopwatch.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                {
                    
                    string value = db.Get(i.ToString());
                    var student = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Student>(value);
                   
                }

                stopwatch.Stop();


                long totalReadTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to read " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

                // Additional metrics
                double avgInsertTime = Math.Round((totalInsertTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average insert time per item: {avgInsertTime} us");

                double avgReadTime = Math.Round((totalReadTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average read time per item: {avgReadTime} us");

                Console.WriteLine($"Execution Finished");
            }
            
        }

        public static void TestZoneTreePerformanceSingleThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Trial for Single thread performance of Zone tree");

            bool InsertAllowed = true;
            bool DeleteEarlierRecords = true;
            string dbPath = "zonetree";

            if (Directory.Exists(dbPath) && DeleteEarlierRecords)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deleting Earlier database directory");

                Directory.Delete(dbPath, true);
            }

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Rocks Db Trial, Max Concurrent Tasks: 1, MaxItems: " + MaxItems);

            // Directory to store the RocksDB database

            stopwatch.Start();

            using var zoneTree = new ZoneTreeFactory<string, string>()
              
              .SetDataDirectory(dbPath)
              .OpenOrCreate();

            using var maintainer = zoneTree.CreateMaintainer();

            // Initialize RocksDB
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"DB Initialization Time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                long totalInsertTime = 0;

                if (InsertAllowed)
                {
                    var random = new Random();
                    stopwatch.Restart();

                    for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                    {
                        var student = new Student
                        {
                            Id = i,
                            Name = $"Student{i}",
                            Age = random.Next(18, 25),
                            GPA = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 4.0, 2),
                            Address = $"Address {i}",
                            PhoneNumber = $"555-0100{i:D4}",
                            Email = $"student{i}@example.com",
                            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-random.Next(1000)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                        };

                        string serializedStudent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(student);

                        zoneTree.Upsert(i.ToString(), serializedStudent);

                    }

                    maintainer.CompleteRunningTasks();


                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    totalInsertTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to insert " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Insertion would be skipped.");
                // Measure the time taken to read items

                List<double> times = new List<double>();
                stopwatch.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                {

                     zoneTree.TryGet(i.ToString(), out string value);// db.Get(i.ToString());
                    var student = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Student>(value);

                }

                stopwatch.Stop();


                long totalReadTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to read " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

                // Additional metrics
                double avgInsertTime = Math.Round((totalInsertTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average insert time per item: {avgInsertTime} us");

                double avgReadTime = Math.Round((totalReadTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average read time per item: {avgReadTime} us");

                Console.WriteLine($"Execution Finished");
            }

        }

        public static void TestConcurrentDictionaryPerformanceMultiTaskThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Trial for Multi Task Read performance of Concurrent Dictionary");


            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            {
                long totalInsertTime = 0;

                // Create a ConcurrentBag with 100,000 Student items
                var bag = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Student>();
                var random = new Random();
                stopwatch.Restart();

                for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                {
                    var student = new Student
                    {
                        Id = i,
                        Name = $"Student{i}",
                        Age = random.Next(18, 25),
                        GPA = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 4.0, 2),
                        Address = $"Address {i}",
                        PhoneNumber = $"555-0100{i:D4}",
                        Email = $"student{i}@example.com",
                        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-random.Next(1000)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                    };

                    bag.TryAdd(i.ToString(), student);
                }



                stopwatch.Stop();
                totalInsertTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to insert " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

                // Measure the time taken to read items

                stopwatch.Restart();

                CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
                var options = new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism =  Environment.ProcessorCount, // Adjust as needed
                    CancellationToken = ct, // You can use cancellation token if needed
                    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default,

                };

                var pfResulst = Parallel.ForEach(bag, options, item =>
                {

                    var studentID = item.Value.Id;
                    var gpa = item.Value.GPA;
                });

                while(!pfResulst.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                }


                stopwatch.Stop();
                double totalReadTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to read " + MaxItems + " items: " + totalReadTime + " ms");

                // Additional metrics
                double avgInsertTime = Math.Round((totalInsertTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average insert time per item: {avgInsertTime} us");

                double avgReadTime = Math.Round((totalReadTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average read time per item: {avgReadTime} us");

                Console.WriteLine($"Test Finished");
            }

        }

        public static void TestRocksDBPerformanceMultiThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Trial for Multi task read performance of RocksDB");

            bool InsertAllowed = true;
            bool DeleteEarlierRecords = true;
            string dbPath = "rocksdb";

            if (Directory.Exists(dbPath) && DeleteEarlierRecords)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deleting Earlier database directory");

                Directory.Delete(dbPath, true);
            }

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Rocks Db Trial, Max Concurrent Tasks: 1, MaxItems: " + MaxItems);

            // Directory to store the RocksDB database

            stopwatch.Start();
            var options = new DbOptions().SetCreateIfMissing(true);

            // Initialize RocksDB
            using (var db = RocksDb.Open(options, dbPath))
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"DB Initialization Time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                long totalInsertTime = 0;

                if (InsertAllowed)
                {
                    var random = new Random();
                    stopwatch.Restart();

                    for (int i = 0; i < MaxItems; i++)
                    {
                        var student = new Student
                        {
                            Id = i,
                            Name = $"Student{i}",
                            Age = random.Next(18, 25),
                            GPA = Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 4.0, 2),
                            Address = $"Address {i}",
                            PhoneNumber = $"555-0100{i:D4}",
                            Email = $"student{i}@example.com",
                            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-random.Next(1000)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                        };

                        string serializedStudent = JsonSerializer.Serialize(student);

                        db.Put(i.ToString(), serializedStudent);

                    }



                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    totalInsertTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to insert " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Insertion would be skipped.");
                // Measure the time taken to read items

                List<double> times = new List<double>();
                stopwatch.Restart();

                CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
                var pfoptions = new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, // Adjust as needed
                    CancellationToken = ct, // You can use cancellation token if needed
                    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default,

                };

                var pfResulst = Parallel.For(0,MaxItems, pfoptions, i =>
                {
                    string value = db.Get(i.ToString());
                    var student = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Student>(value);

                    var studentID = student.Id;
                    var gpa = student.GPA;
                });

                while (!pfResulst.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                }


               

                stopwatch.Stop();


                long totalReadTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to read " + MaxItems + " items: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

                // Additional metrics
                double avgInsertTime = Math.Round((totalInsertTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average insert time per item: {avgInsertTime} us");

                double avgReadTime = Math.Round((totalReadTime / (double)MaxItems) * 1000, 1);
                Console.WriteLine($"Average read time per item: {avgReadTime} us");

                Console.WriteLine($"Execution Finished");
            }

        }

        public class Student
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public double GPA { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        }
    }

}

Performance Results:
Performance Results for test Run

Single thread performance of Zone tree


DB Initialization Time: 136 ms
Time taken to insert 10000000 items: 67030 ms
Time taken to read 10000000 items: 41052 ms
Average insert time per item: 6.7 us
Average read time per item: 4.1 us



Single thread performance of Concurrent Dictionary


Time taken to insert 10000000 items: 21166 ms 
Time taken to read 10000000 items: 1658 ms 
Average insert time per item: 2.1 us 
Average read time per item: 0.2 us



Single thread performance of RocksDB


Initiating Rocks Db Trial, Max Concurrent Tasks: 1, MaxItems: 10000000
DB Initialization Time: 748 ms 
Time taken to insert 10000000 items:65248 ms 
Time taken to read 10000000 items: 45764 ms 
Average inserttime per item: 6.5 us 
Average read time per item: 4.6 us



Multitask Read performance of Concurrent Dictionary


Time taken to insert 10000000 items: 20733 ms 
Time taken to read 10000000 items: 1322 ms
Average insert time per item: 2.1 us 
Average read time per item: 0.1 us



Multitask read performance of RocksDB


Initiating Rocks Db Trial, Max Concurrent Tasks: 1, MaxItems: 10000000
DB Initialization Time: 32 ms  
Time taken to insert 10000000 items: 74728 ms  
Time taken to read 10000000 items: 38001 ms  
Average insert time per item: 7.5 us
Average read time per item: 3.8 us


**Here is my conclusion: **
Concurrent Dictionary offered a very fast read performance, while comparable Write performance. The reason to add ConcurrentDictionary here was just as a reference, I do realize comparing a disk based persistent store with in-memory collection isn't and entirely fair deal.
While Zonetree offered faster performance, I noticed that the max memory during trial by ZoneTree and ConcurrentDictionary both equated 5.3GB which meant at a certain point of time all values were actually sitting in memory while ZoneTree's 'maintainer' did its job. This is a clear disadvantage for ZoneTree, optimal memory utilization is the reason to turn towards persistent Key Value stores in the first place.
As for RocksDB, the max memory utilization stayed below 130 MB, the database did not utilize more than 550 MB of diskspace. And reading/writing was achievable in <10 us on average. Additionally, it seems RocksDB handles concurrency well, while a multi-thread application wouldn't be able to extract higher performance, built in protection against concurrency protection (within Same process though) is welcome.

A single measurement is meaningless, even if it tries to load a lot of items. Those timings are susceptible to warmup effects, garbage collections and the machine's load. Use BenchmarkDotNet instead, the de-facto standard for .NET benchmarks. Defacto as in nobody will even look at numbers that weren't created by it. BenchMarkDotNet repeats a test long enough for results to stabilize and collect statistically significant measurements. If the repeated tests vary too wildly, it will tell you so. It also handles GC delays which this code doesn't.

The very fact you're creating 10M items each time means there are 10M orphaned objects when the next test runs. The garbage collector can run during that test, freezing the application until it collects all of them. Worse, the fact you serialize to JSON  results in at least another 10M temporary strings.

With so many temporary strings flying around, memory usage will be a big problem. BDN will show GC statistics and even memory usage for each test. I suggest creating the data in advance outside the test methods. BDN can also handle passing data to tests without measuring the data creation time

Thanks Panagiotis, I did run the tests seperately to get the numbers, so the effect of dangling stuff in memory should be nullified. if I can find some time, I will update with BenchmarkDotNet.

Your code is misleading the performance metrics.
Because you wait for compaction by calling CompleteRunningTasks() for ZoneTree, but for RocksDb you don't do the same.
For memory optimization, RocksDb throttles insert requests. You can do the same for ZoneTree, there is no built in throttling for inserts.
It is hard to compare these products because they have several parameters to optimize memory utilization and performance.

As I mentioned, the fundamental reason to go for on disk Key Value stores vs in Memory stored collections is to minimize memory usage.  It would be great if you can share some code on how ZoneTree could offer comparable performance while keeping memory usage to as low as RocksDb(which saturates at a very low value and stays constant). I am happy to amend my answer that helps do a fairer comparison while having comparable memory usage/execution time.

RocksDB slows down writes as documented here: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Write-Stalls
You can do the similar using ZoneTree. To do this, you have to control when to stop or slowdown writes by looking into in memory records count. These values are available through API.
Anyway, the numbers in your post are wrong as described on my answer. Could you please rerun tests with latest version and then update the numbers showing correct performance difference?
Thank you.

Minimizing memory usage is not ultimate single fundamental goal. The tradeoff between memory efficiency and performance can vary per project or business needs.
